# Displaying punctuation in a button's data attribute

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to put a PHP variable in a button data attribute however weird characters are showing up instead of the punctuation. As an example instead of an apostrophe `&#39;` is showing up instead. The variable is normal everywhere else on the page. How can I fix this?

```
<button id="coolButton"data-name="<?PHP echo $name;?>"
```

Comment: So what is the output after the PHP runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an space between the final of id and the beginning of data-name

```
<button id="coolButton" data-name="<?PHP echo $name;?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the quotes at the wrong place

Instead of this:

```
<button id="coolButton"data-name="<?PHP echo $name;?>"
```

Try this:

```
<button id="coolButton" data-name="<?PHP echo $name; ?>">
```

You also didn't close the button tag, only the php part. 
Sorry for my bad english